# Why is the message not echoing?

Tags: php, mysql, database

So I have a database that contains how many codes are left, and my code basically echos how many I have left, but here's the issue. I don't see it echoing anything. I've also done curl and nothing comes up,  Here's my code. Error reporting is on, and nothing is being displayed also. Any ideas?

```
  <?php
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
 class RedeemAPI {
    private $db;

    // Constructor - open DB connection
    function __construct() {
        $this->db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'x', 'promos');
        $this->db->autocommit(FALSE);
    }

    // Destructor - close DB connection
    function __destruct() {
        $this->db->close();
    }

    // Main method to redeem a code
    function redeem() {
        // Print all codes in database
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT id, code, unlock_code, uses_remaining FROM rw_promo_code');
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $code, $unlock_code, $uses_remaining);
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            echo "$code has $uses_remaining uses remaining!";
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: And the code that actually calls the functions…?

Comment: Did you instantiate the class?

Comment: Before you close $stmt, try to echo the $error property: `echo $stmt->error;`

Comment: Where have you called the function and initiated the class? Have you posted the entire code that you are using?

Comment: Don't get anything. @BrandonWhite

Comment: And how and where to you call that method?

Comment: I'm calling it with `$api = new RedeemAPI;` and 
`$api->redeem();` @PatrickQ

Comment: initiate the class in the same file!

Comment: Do you have data in table rw_promo_code?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you are actually creating an object of this class. If this is your full code, you are not initiating the class.

Add the following to your code if there are no other pages and the `redeem()` function should be executed.

```
$apiobject = new RedeemAPI();
$apiobject->redeem();
```